# Promise wrong order execution

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello Im chaining promises but the results im getting are not what Im expecting

belowe the code:

```
createFile(event.body)
        .then(() => readFile()) 
        .then((data) => uploadToS3(data))
        .then(() => deleteTmp())
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

and functions:

```
async function createFile(fileBinary) {
    return await fs.writeFile(TMP_FILE, fileBinary, 'binary', (err) => {
        if (err) {
            throw {error: 'File upload error_stage1'}
        }
        return;
    });
}

async function readFile() {
return await (fs.readFile(TMP_FILE, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        throw {error: 'File upload error_stage2'}
    }
    console.log('read file')
    return data;
}));
}

async function uploadToS3(data) {
    console.log('upload s3')
    const uploadParams = {Bucket: myBucket, Key: myKey, Body: data};
    return await s3.putObject(uploadParams, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw {error: 'File upload error_stage3'}
        }
        return data;
    });
}

async function deleteTmp() {
    fs.unlink(TMP_FILE, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            throw {error: 'File upload error_stage3'}
        }
    })
}
```

console.logs:

```
upload s3
read file
```

so from the console logs we can see that the function uploads3 gets executed before read file and that is kind of against the chain order. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `readFile` function returns a promise that is resolved without waiting for the file to be read, that is because you've used [`Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)

You need to return a new promise that resolves after the file is read.
For example:

```
function readFile() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       fs.readFile(TMP_FILE, (err, data) => {
           if (err) {
               console.log(err)
               throw {error: 'File upload error_stage2'}
           }
           console.log('read file')
           resolve(data);
       })
    })
}
```

In the `uploadToS3` you have this `return await s2.putObject....` which won't work because `s3.putObject` doesn't return a promise. You'll have to do something similar in order to wait for the file to be uploaded:

```
function uploadToS3(data) {
    const uploadParams = {Bucket: myBucket, Key: myKey, Body: data};
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.putObject(uploadParams, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                throw {error: 'File upload error_stage3'}
            }
            resolve(data);
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like ReadFile is returning a promise, which gets executed later while uploadToS3 doesn't return a promise, so it gets executed in the call.

I don't have an environment set up to test it, but maybe you're wanting to do something like this:

```
createFile(event.body)
        .then(() => readFile()
                .then((data) => uploadToS3(data))
                .then(() => deleteTmp())) // <- close-parenthesis here.
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Kind of. `updateToS3` isn't actually waiting for the callback that the OP passed in to get executed before returning. He's `await`-ing a synchronous function call (it doesn't return a promise, it takes a callback which is not the same) so the `await` returns immediately (probably with undefined) before the callback gets executed.

Comment: well I tried to .then on the 'inside' of first async call, but it gave the same results, the one with new Promise rsolve reject did the job. Which I suppose is connected to @Titus response, that those functions donot return promises

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are mixing up chaining calls to functions that return Promises, with async functions.

Stick to one of the other and you should be fine.

A: Make all your functions async, and then simply call them sequentially

or

B: Have all your functions return Promises